# Printing Price out?

Tags: c#

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq;
using System.Text; using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment12 {
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           bool found;
           string[] toppings = { "cheese", "pepperoni", "green pepper", "onion", "mushroom" };
           double[] price = { 1.30, 1.90, 1.80, 1.70, 1.60 };

           Console.WriteLine("Choose a topping: cheese, pepperoni, green pepper, onion or mushroom");
           Console.WriteLine("Please type the topping that you want - exactly as it appears above:");
           string order = Console.ReadLine();
           Console.WriteLine("\nYou chose: " + order);

           found = false;
           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
           {
               if (order.Equals(toppings[i]))
               {
                   found = true;
               }
           }
           if (!found)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("The product " + order + " was not found, please try again!!!!!!\n");
               Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true);
               return;
           }
// The problem is here with the local variable "price"
           Console.WriteLine("The price of " + order + " is $" + price);
// I also tried 1.30, 1.90, 1.80, 1.70, 1.60 but still not working
           Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you search for your topping, you need to remember the price:

```
found = false;
double priceFound = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (order.Equals(toppings[i]))
    {
        found = true;
        priceFound = price[i]; // store the found price
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("The price of " + order + " is $" + priceFound);
```

However, you don't need to iterate through the array yourself.
It all can be done easier using [`Array.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx). This method returns the index of an item in array, and returns `-1` if item has not been found.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string[] toppings = { "cheese", "pepperoni", "green pepper", "onion", "mushroom" };
   double[] price = { 1.30, 1.90, 1.80, 1.70, 1.60 };

   Console.WriteLine("Choose a topping: cheese, pepperoni, green pepper, onion or mushroom");
   Console.WriteLine("Please type the topping that you want - exactly as it appears above:");
   string order = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine("\nYou chose: " + order);

   int index = topping.IndexOf(order);

   if (index == -1)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("The product " + order + " was not found, please try again!!!!!!\n");
       Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true);
       return;
   }

   Console.WriteLine("The price of " + order + " is $" + price[index]);
   Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to close"); 
   Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: @AnassElbekkari What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it show compile error, throws a run-time exception or gives wrong results?

Comment: Thank you.  It works now.  I used the first solution.